# Using document.getElementsByClassName in Testcafe

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I have a menu that always has the same structure, but the IDs can change from one installation to another. the only thing that stays the same is the heading (in my case "Plugins"). I call the `document.getElementsByClassName` function with a `Selector` inside my test:

```
var slides = Selector(() =>{
    return document.getElementsByClassName("c-p-header-text");
});
```

Every heading of an menu element has the `c-p-header-text` class. Here is what a menu heading element looks like:

```
<div id="ext-comp-1002" class="c-p c-tree c-p-collapsed" style="width: auto;">
     <div class="c-p-header c-unselectable c-accordion-hd" id="ext-gen135" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <div class="c-tool c-tool-toggle" id="ext-gen140">&nbsp;</div>
        <img src="/backEnd/images/s.gif" class="c-p-inline-icon order"><span class="c-p-header-text" id="ext-gen150">Plugins</span>
     </div>
```

It would be easy to use `await t.click("#ext-gen150")` but it is not safe that it is always this id.

here is what i tried:

```
await t
    .click('#sites__db');
var slides = Selector(() =>{
    return document.getElementsByClassName("c-p-header-text");
});
console.log("[DEBUG]" + slides);
console.log("[DEBUG] found " + slides.length + " elements");
for(var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++)
{
    var txtOfCurrElem = slides.item(i).innerText; 
    console.log("[DEBUG "+ i +"] Text: " + txtOfCurrElem);
}
```

Running this test give me the following output:

```
[DEBUG]function __$$clientFunction$$() {
        var testRun = builder.getBoundTestRun() || _testRunTracker2.default.resolveContextTestRun();
        var callsite = (0, _getCallsite.getCallsiteForMethod)(builder.callsiteNames.execution);
        var args = [];

        // OPTIMIZATION: don't leak `arguments` object.
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            args.push(arguments[i]);
        }return builder._executeCommand(args, testRun, callsite);
    }
[DEBUG] found 0 elements
```

The plan is to find the element (with the heading "Plugins") and then click on it when the test continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple answer to my question. I use the `.withText` option to click on the Plugins element:

```
.click(Selector('span').withText("Plugins"))
```

Since this name is also unique, it is always the correct element that gets clicked. I do not know if it would have worked with the solution from @AndreyBelym if my site is not an extJS web application.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't have to use `document.getElementsByClassName` in this case. You can just use CSS class selector instead:

   ```
   var slides = Selector('.c-p-header-text');
   ```
2. You should use the `count` property when dealing with an array of Selectors. [docs](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors.html#check-if-an-element-exists). Also, element properties, like `exists`, `count`, and [DOM node state properties](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/dom-node-state.html) are Promisified, so when you use them not in `t.expect`, you should use the `await` keyword:

   ```
   var count = await slides.length;

   console.log("[DEBUG] found " + count + " elements");

   for(var i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
       var txtOfCurrElem = await slides.nth(i).innerText; 
       console.log("[DEBUG "+ i +"] Text: " + txtOfCurrElem);
   }
   ```

Comment: I changed my code to your suggestion but I still get no results. Count is still 0. Maybe it does not work because I want to test a extJS web application?